# LINQ's Select inside Task.Run skipping first value whereas ForEach does not

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, task

I have a function

```
public Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetVersionsAsync<T>(string key)
{
    var request = GetVersionsRequestBuilder.Create(_databaseName, _collectionName).WithKey(key);

    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var records = _myReader.GetAllVersionsForKey(request);        

        var returnValue = records.Select(record =>
        {
            var document = _mySerializer.Deserialize<T>(record.document);
            return document;
        });

        return returnValue;
    });
}
```

This is skipping first value and giving all rest results

However, if I change the LINQ part to ForEach, then it gives all records

```
var returnValue = new List<T>();

foreach (var record in records)
{
    var document = _mySerializer.Deserialize<T>(record.document);
    returnValue.Add(document);
}

return returnValue as IEnumerable<T>;
```

Is this due to LINQ's Select projection being inside `Task.Run`?

Comment: What are `_myReader` and `_mySerializer` ? How thread-safe are those?

Comment: Those are my database Reader and Serializer which get the results and de-serialise them respectively. They are identical in both LINQ and ForEach snippet.

Answer (score 3):

Do *not* mix IEnumerables and Tasks. Deferred Execution and parallel execution at the same time are really not playing well together.

I don't know what *specifically* trigger your weird behavior, but generally speaking, your task is useless, because it does not do what you think it does. It does *not* deserialize all elements. The task is done almost immediately, and it returns the state-machine that is your IEnumerable. Only when you materialize it, after your task is done, it will actually *do* what you intend to do with the LinQ.

So, do not mix it. If you want it to run async, do so, but materialize it:

```
public Task<List<T>> GetVersionsAsync<T>(string key)
{
    var request = GetVersionsRequestBuilder.Create(_databaseName, _collectionName).WithKey(key);

    return Task.Run(() =>
    {
        var records = _myReader.GetAllVersionsForKey(request);        

        var returnValue = records.Select(
            record => _mySerializer.Deserialize<T>(record.document)
        ).ToList(); // materialize it

        return returnValue;
    });
}
```

What you propbably *should* do is make the method async and call the async version of your database reader instead of faking it.

Comment: +1. I would add that [eliding async and await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) is probably not a good idea in this case, because an error in the `GetVersionsRequestBuilder.Create` call will not be wrapped in the resulting `Task`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't disagree with Nvoigt's advice but I ran two dummy versions of the code.  The first version still uses IEnumerable and the second materializes into the List type.  I got the same result with each which is that all the results were returned as expected.  I have to conclude then that the issue is inside of the Deserialize call.

V1:

```
    static async Task Main()
    {
        var insideTask = await GetFruitsAsync();
        foreach (var obj in insideTask)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", obj);
        }
        return;
    }

    public static Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetFruitsAsync()
    {
        IEnumerable<string> fruits = new string[] { "apple", "banana", "mango", "orange",
                  "passionfruit", "grape" };

        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var query = fruits.Select(fruit =>
            {
                var returnValue = fruit.Substring(0, 2);
                return returnValue;
            });
            return query;
        });
    }
```

V2:

```
    static async Task Main()
    {
        var insideTask = await GetFruitsAsync();
        foreach (var obj in insideTask)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", obj);
        }
        return;
    }

    public static Task<List<string>> GetFruitsAsync()
    {
        List<string> fruits = new List<string> { "apple", "banana", "mango", "orange",
                  "passionfruit", "grape" };

        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var query = fruits.Select(fruit =>
            {
                var returnValue = fruit.Substring(0, 2);
                return returnValue;
            });
            return query.ToList();
        });
    }
```